# Combine result from Forms from Chain

Tags: c#, botframework

How combine results from Forms into one result and post result to user?
I need to set Declaration property from Chain and post completed SupportRequest to user.
In documentation I see Chain.Fold method but I don't know how to use it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-dialogs.

My code:

```
public enum SystemSelection { SharePoint, BizTalk, Azure, Office365 };
public enum RequestType { Bug, SupportRequest, Question };
public enum Importance { Blocking, High, Medium, Low };

[Serializable]
class Declaration
{
    public string Type;
    public string Amount;
    public string Date;

    public static IForm<Declaration> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<Declaration>()
                .Message("Add a declaration")
                .Build();
    }
}

[Serializable]
class SupportRequest
{
    public SystemSelection? SystemSelection;
    public RequestType? RequestType;
    public Importance? Importance;
    //need to setup this property
    public Declaration Declaration;

    public static IForm<SupportRequest> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<SupportRequest>()
                .Message("Welcome to the simple support bot!")
                .AddRemainingFields()
                .Build();
    }

    internal static IDialog<SupportRequest> MakeRootDialog()
    {
        var dlg = from x in FormDialog.FromForm(SupportRequest.BuildForm)
                  from y in FormDialog.FromForm(Declaration.BuildForm)
                  select x;
        return dlg;
    }

    internal static IDialog<Declaration> MakeRootDialog2()
    {
        SupportRequest t = null;
        var dlg = Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(SupportRequest.BuildForm))
        .ContinueWith<SupportRequest, Declaration>(async (ctx, sr) =>
        {
            t = await sr;
            return FormDialog.FromForm(Declaration.BuildForm);
        });

        return dlg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are using Chain?

Comment: @EzequielJadib I don't know another way to get value of complex type like Declaration from user - as I see BotFramework supports only primitive types in FormFlow. I use chain to call inner form to get data from user. Do you suggest another approach? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I followed you, you are trying to call a form after the first form completed?

Comment: yes. i want to get result from second form and set property Declaration in first form. And return completed SupportRequest as a result of Chain.